# Function does not execute sequentially

Tags: solidity, javascript

I'm trying to check in a JavaScript function if checkVehicleExists returns a true or false before proceeding with my if else statement which will depend on whether checkVehicleExists is true or false.

However, the if else statement is executing before the checkVehicleExists and producing an error of "check is undefined".

How do I make my JavaScript function execute sequentially such that the if else statement comes after checkVehicleExists?

```
    that.checkVehicleExists(newVehicleRegistrationNo, function (error, bool) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        var check = bool;
        console.log("check " + check);
        console.log(1); 
    });

    console.log(2);
    if (check){
        $("#newVehicleRegistrationNo").val("");
        $("#newVehicleBrand").val("");
        $("#newVehicleModel").val("");
        $("#newVehicleOwner").val("");
        $("#newWalletAddress").val("");
        $("#newAmountPayable").val("");
        $("#message").text("Vehicle has already been registered.");
    }
    else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a javascript question and for another place, but I will answer you since you're new contributor, please be careful next time.

By firing `that.checkVehicleExists` you're obviously making request to the blockchain, these requests are asynchronous and do not happen immediateally. And you're also creating variable `check` and then trying to call it out the scope where it is created.

**Solution 1** - wrap everything into one `async` method, read more about javascript `async` and `await` before using it:

```
async function init() {
    var check = await that.checkVehicleExists(newVehicleRegistrationNo);
    console.log("check " + check);
    
    if (check){
        $("#newVehicleRegistrationNo").val("");
        $("#newVehicleBrand").val("");
        $("#newVehicleModel").val("");
        $("#newVehicleOwner").val("");
        $("#newWalletAddress").val("");
        $("#newAmountPayable").val("");
        $("#message").text("Vehicle has already been registered.");
    }
}

init();
```

**Solution 2** - or add your code in the callback of method `that.checkVehicleExists`:

```
that.checkVehicleExists(newVehicleRegistrationNo, function (error, bool) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    var check = bool;
    console.log("check " + check);
    
    if (check){
        $("#newVehicleRegistrationNo").val("");
        $("#newVehicleBrand").val("");
        $("#newVehicleModel").val("");
        $("#newVehicleOwner").val("");
        $("#newWalletAddress").val("");
        $("#newAmountPayable").val("");
        $("#message").text("Vehicle has already been registered.");
    }
});
```

Comment: I see. I'm new to both solidity and javascript and thanks for the help!

Comment: Np, if my answer helped you, please accept it as the answer and give it a upvote so other struggling with the same issue can navigate easy to the answer.